# SyntaxError creating python3 virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I just tried creating a python3 virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper, but it keeps giving me this syntax error:

```
$ mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3 virtualenv_name
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5'
New python executable in /path/to/virtualenvs/virtualenv_name/bin/python3.5
Also creating executable in /path/to/virtualenvs/virtualenv_name/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /path/to/virtualenvs/virtualenv_name/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /path/to/virtualenvs/virtualenv_name/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /path/to/virtualenvs/virtualenv_name/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /path/to/virtualenvs/virtualenv_name/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /path/to/virtualenvs/virtualenv_name/bin/get_env_details
virtualenv virtualenv_name activated.

  File "<string>", line 1
    import distutils; print distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib()
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's my `mkvirtualenv` version:

```
$ mkvirtualenv --version
15.0.3
```

Comment: Please provide the `mkvirtualenv` version. Recent version shouldn't expose the `print` as statement, while their are [tested for python 3](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/overview).

Comment: @aluriak I've edited my post to include the version.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue might occur, when you'd upgrade `pip` for python (python 2.7.x is default in Linux OS like ubuntu/mint) and forgot to upgrade `pip` for python3.